# How do I resolve this error in trying to build v8

Tags: android, macos, v8

I'm trying to build v8 for Android on MacOS. I'm encountering an error during the build.

The build command that I am using is

`ninja -C out.gn/arm.release d8`

The arguments (as viewed from `gn args out.gn/arm.release` ) are as follows.

```
android_sdk_root= "/Users/joel/Library/Android/sdk/"
android_ndk_version = "r22"
v8_static_library = true

target_os = "android"      # These lines need to be changed manually
target_cpu = "arm64"       # as v8gen.py assumes a simulator build.
v8_target_cpu = "arm64"
is_component_build = false
```

The build is running into an error. I've got not clue how to get around this. When the error is encountered, this is the error that is produced. I noticed that the lines appear to all say

`../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory`

Any idea how to get around this? The full output is as follows.

```
[1/2020] AR clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_bigint.a
**FAILED: clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_bigint.a 
rm -f clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_bigint.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar"  -r -c -s -D clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_bigint.a "@clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_bigint.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[2/2020] AR clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_libbase.a
FAILED: clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_libbase.a 
rm -f clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_libbase.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar"  -r -c -s -D clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_libbase.a "@clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/libv8_libbase.a.rsp"**
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[3/2020] AR clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a
FAILED: clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a 
rm -f clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar"  -r -c -s -D clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a "@clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[4/2020] AR clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a
FAILED: clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a 
rm -f clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar"  -r -c -s -D clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a "@clang_x64_v8_arm64/obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[5/2020] AR obj/libv8_libbase.a
FAILED: obj/libv8_libbase.a 
rm -f obj/libv8_libbase.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar" -T -r -c -s -D obj/libv8_libbase.a @"obj/libv8_libbase.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[6/2020] AR obj/libv8_bigint.a
FAILED: obj/libv8_bigint.a 
rm -f obj/libv8_bigint.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar" -T -r -c -s -D obj/libv8_bigint.a @"obj/libv8_bigint.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[7/2020] AR obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a
FAILED: obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a 
rm -f obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar" -T -r -c -s -D obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a @"obj/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
[8/2020] AR obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a
FAILED: obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a 
rm -f obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a && "../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar" -T -r -c -s -D obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a @"obj/third_party/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a.rsp"
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar: No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer found. While instructions are provided on building V8 on macOS, those instructions refer to actions not supported anymore. For a successful build, use linux.